# Queuing multiple request before making http call to external service - spring webflux and projectreactor

Tags: java, reactive-programming, batch-processing, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using spring webflux and I would like to queue multiple requests before sending an http call to external system using WebClient and would like to know what is the best practice to do such requirement.

```
@GetMapping
Mono<Result> get(@RequestParam Optional<String> input) {
    //Here I have to somehow keep the input and make a call when I have X items, then I can write to response, how this need to be done? Also what sort of Mono has to be return here?
}
```

I have found this which can be a solution but still a bit unclear https://ducmanhphan.github.io/2019-08-25-How-to-use-Processor-in-Reactor-Java/
Would be appreciated if anybody explains.

Comment: Just curious. Lets say X is 10. First user sends a request. Should he wait for remaining 9 users to send the request to this controller. Can you add more info related to this? also once we get 10 requests, should all the 10 users get the same response?

Comment: Hi Vins, I know it does not sound very logical but yes that is the requirement and also time is another constrains, so we have to make a call when we have X items or the item has already waited for Y milliseconds but for simplicity, let's say we only make a call when we have X items.

Comment: Making a call once you have X items is very simple. My only confusion is - should we block X users till then? All the users will get the same response of the webclient which you make after accumulating X items?